# PyQt and QwtPlot - how to change ticks direction?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwt

I have a Qt Designer file with QwtPlot widget.
Question: how to change Ticks direction with python code?

QwtPlot widget is accessible by `self.ui.qwtPlot1` code line.
Below a picture is with view of axis - how to make qwtPlot axis look like this?
Thank You All for answers!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uxp7.png

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the set_axis_direction() method?

```
self.ui.qwtPlot1.set_axis_direction(0, True)
```

or if self.ui.qwtPlot1 is a curvewidget then you might use:

```
self.ui.qwtPlot1.plot.set_axis_direction(0, True)
```

cheerio